# Gain of a differential amplifier with active load

Tags: mosfet, differential, gain

Can anyone help me to find which is the type for the gain of this differential amplifier for common mode input.I had find that is **Acm = 1/(gm3*2*ro5)**.Can anyone help me if this result is correct and how I can prove it?

[image]

Comment: Would you be able to find the differential gain for common mode input if you would replace the Q5 and the current mirror with a resistor?

Comment: differential gain is gm2 *(ro2//ro4)

Comment: Do you know common mode gain for this circuirt http://obrazki.elektroda.pl/7016185300_1496676482.png

Comment: yes it is Acm = -gmRD /(1+2gmRSS)